# how do I keep a cython variable alive?

Tags: c, cython

I have a bytes string which is passed into a cython method, and I need to pass it into a c function:

```
def stuff(bytes b):
    #b is b'something'
    some_c_function(b, len(b))
```

The pointer I passed in is saved to some struct inside C-land. By the time it's used, `b` has disappeared, so I get a segmentation fault. How do I keep it alive outside of the function?

I tried something like this:

```
from libc.stdlib import malloc, memcpy

def stuff(bytes b):
    cdef char *data
    data_len = len(b)
    data = malloc(data_len)
    memcpy(data, b, data_len)
    some_c_function(data, data_len)
```

But I get an error on the `malloc` call: `Obtaining char * from temporary Python value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to `cimport` the `malloc` function, otherwise Cython handles the import as default Python import and thinks `malloc` is a ordinary Python function.
2. `data_len` should be `len(b) + 1` and the last byte must be set to `0`, i.e.
   `data[data_len - 1] = 0`. This is the way how a string is terminated in C/C++.
3. After you've `cimport`-ed `malloc` and Cython treats the function as a C-function, you will need to make a cast, otherwise the Cython compiler will complain.

   `data = <char*> malloc(data_len)`
4. What **you** have `malloc`-ed, needs to be freed **by yourself**. Ensure that this will happen.